# Unable to plot hclust object with ggtree

Tags: r, hclust, ggtree

I am trying to plot a dendrogram from a `hclust` object with `ggtree` but I keep getting the same error message:

```
Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class hclust
```

I have been extensively looking for a solution, but found none. Furthermore, I have learned that `ggtree` [does support](https://github.com/GuangchuangYu/ggtree-current-protocols#basic-protocol-2) `hclust` objects, which has confused me even more. From [here](https://yulab-smu.github.io/treedata-book/chapter9.html#dendrogram):

> The ggtree package supports most of the hierarchical clustering
>   objects defined in the R community, including `hclust` and `dendrogram` as
>   well as `agnes`, `diana` and `twins` that defined in the cluster package.

I have borrowed a reproducible example from the link above:

```
hc <- hclust(dist(mtcars))
p <- ggtree(hc, linetype='dashed')
```

Which, again, gives me the abovementioned error. If I use `rlang::last_error()` to get a bit of context, I get:

```
<error/rlang_error>
`data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class hclust
Backtrace:
 1. ggtree::ggtree(hc, linetype = "dashed")
 3. ggplot2:::ggplot.default(...)
 5. ggplot2:::fortify.default(data, ...)
```

And if I use rlang::last_trace() to get a bit further information:

```
<error/rlang_error>
`data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class hclust
Backtrace:
    x
 1. \-ggtree::ggtree(hc, linetype = "dashed")
 2.   +-ggplot2::ggplot(...)
 3.   \-ggplot2:::ggplot.default(...)
 4.     +-ggplot2::fortify(data, ...)
 5.     \-ggplot2:::fortify.default(data, ...)
```

But I can really see what is wrong...

Comment: so, ultimately, is your `data` a data.frame as that seems the bar to pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve my issue. I will post it in case it is of help for someone else in the future.

Apparently, I was running an older version of `ggtree` which was not being correctly updated when I reinstalled `ggtree` from Bioconductor, I am not sure why. Anyway, I tried to reinstall it by explicitly setting the `version` argument in the installation call:

```
BiocManager::install("ggtree", version = "3.10")
```

And then I could successfully run my reproducible example:

```
hc <- hclust(dist(mtcars))
p <- ggtree(hc, linetype='dashed')
```

[image]

Note that as a previous workaround, I had managed to plot the `hcluster` object with `ggtree` by transforming it to a `phylo` object with the `as.phylo()` function from the `ape` package:

```
hc <- hclust(dist(mtcars))
hc <- ape::as.phylo(hc)
p <- ggtree(hc, linetype='dashed')
```